# start an activity without showing it at start up

Tags: android, startup, runnable

I've several question that is like my question but it is too complicated for me and my dilemma. what i just want is to start my second activity without it showing at start up. i used this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

it does the job but the second activity starts and show first than the main activity which is not what i want. i need to start my second activity in the main activity because i am running a runnable that needs to fill a text view of a new value during a set amount of time. if the second activity does not start at startup the app throws a NullPointerException

Comment: sorry, what information do want me to add. and if you could kindly give me a nice tutorial about fragment i'll appreciate it

Comment: hey can i just start the activity like how we can call anytime a form's Form_Load in VB6